# What's happening with Ubuntu kernel development for generic kernels?

Tags: kernel

Please could someone kindly tell me what's happening with ubuntu kernel development. Ever since Covid-19 lock down all the kernels are shown as "mainline test" and appear to the result of an automated script. i.e. NOT a complete installable generic kernel.

Please could someone tell me what the difference is between a "mainline test" and a "mainline build". I am assuming that the mainline tests are full of errors & therefore incomplete & NOT installable.

**Further question is, does anyone know when the next mainline build (generic kernel) will be released? if so when?**

Comment: Where are you looking for new kernels?

Comment: For example of what I'm talking about here, https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.8.5/ But this isn't a working kernel. Why is there no explanation or communication about the stalled generic kernel process.

Comment: There is never any communication when the mainline builds are broken. Typically the kernel team doesn't even know about it until someone (often me) goes on irc and tells them.